# Json schema require patternProperty

Tags: jsonschema

Is there way to require patternProperty?

```
{
  "type": "object", 
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema", 
  "patternProperties": {
    "^proper_.+_ty$": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

Can I make this "^proper_.+_ty$" to be required or require arbitrary key in any other way?

Answer (score 2):

No, it can't be done.  But, discussions are underway as I type this to develop the next version of JSON Schema.  I encourage you to go to https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec and file an issue asking that something be included in the next iteration to handle this case.